# Ruby on Rails: Get json from controller in Javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

in my controller I've some json:

votes_controller.rb:

```
def create
  ...
  vote_status = current_user.user_votes.pluck(:recipient_uid).include?(@user.uid)
  render json: vote_status
end
```

I need to get `vote_status` in javascript file

votes.js:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".doWant").click( function () {
    var status = vote_status.evalJSON();
    var uid = $(this).parents("#dialog")[0];
    var username = $(this).parents("#dialog")[0];
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/votes' + "?uid=" + $(uid).attr("data-user-uid") + "&username=" + $(username).attr("data-user-username"),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
          console.log(data)
        }
      });
    };
  });
});
```

But there is an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: vote_status is not defined`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: How / when is that `votes_controller` action called?

Comment: where does **vote_status** in **var status = vote_status.evalJSON();** defined?

Comment: @enchante that is my question. I dont know clearly how and where should I defined it. How can I get json from controller in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **vote_status** is returned in success json callback, init the status there

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/votes' + "?uid=" + $(uid).attr("data-user-uid") + "&username=" + $(username).attr("data-user-username"),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      var status = JSON.parse(data);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not defining this variable:

```
var status = vote_status.evalJSON();
```

You must define that variable.

It seems likely that you intended for that code to go into the `success` function, which returns the data from the ajax call as the first argument in that function:

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data)
}
```

Comment: but how should I define this variable? I need to get value of json from `votes_controller`

Comment: @Gvcci The `data` variable contains the rendered `vote_status` data.